# Json encode returns ? marks for Chinese characters

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have Names which are stored using `utf8_unicode_ci` in database.

Ajax dataType property is `dataType:"json"`

And this is the php code:

```
$names = mysql_query($query);

$name_arr = array();
while($name = mysql_fetch_assoc($names)) {
    $name_arr[] = $name;
}

echo json_encode($name_arr);
```

It returns `???` replacing Chinese characters. I think I didn't do double encode. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sending the data in UTF8, too? Try `header("Content-Encoding: utf-8");`.

Comment: `json_encode()` could also be the problem. Please remove it and try it again (of course, it won't be valid JSON).

Comment: I did. I tried to return `text` instead of `json`. So I just echo'ed the name, still returned the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,17168,17515#msg-17515

Comment: Worked perfectly. Only need the code lines 5 & 6 to add the enconding type to the text.